# How to setup an Android project using GAE/J and AWS S3 jars?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been dealing with this problem today and I still can't find any solution. I have an App Engine connected Android project that makes calls to GAE Datastore (via Endpoints) and to AWS S3 using AmazonS3Client. I'm up to the point that I have to upload a photo file from the camera to S3 and its respective meta-data to a Datastore Entity (Photo.java). Unfortunately, even though I think my code is right, I can't run the sample because there are multiple files that define a class which is probably a collission between aws-android-sdk-X.X.X-debug.jar and one of the GAE client jars.

Here is my console log:

```
[2013-10-06 20:15:15 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define     Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant;
[2013-10-06 20:15:15 - moodstream_final] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant;
```

What can I do in this case? I don't want to mess up with the default jars imported from GAE and I don't know what to import from aws libs to avoid this collission.

**EDIT**

I also tried importing only the aws-android-sdk-X.X.X-s3.jar instead of the whole debug jar. The program now runs, but when is time to create the AmazonS3Client I get the following error:

```
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at com.moodstream.activity.CreatePhotoActivity.<init>(CreatePhotoActivity.java:42)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 02:07:06.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't get it because the AmazonS3Client is in the s3 jar as well. Therefore, still stuck :S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!! I managed to fix the dual file collission deleting the jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar from my libs folder.